# Geometry of schemes by Eisenbud and Harris

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, textbook-recommendation

I have some background of algebraic geometry.

I am now trying to study schemes from book Geometry of schemes by Eisenbud and Harris.

I was checking recommendations for books on algebraic geometry and see that one user suggested this book but with a comment

> Oh, I'm a big fan of the book. I'm just warning that if you read it all the way through, you still won't know the 'basics' of algebraic geometry.

I am now confused whether to continue reading this or try some other book. I like the presentation as of now, I am looking at first chapter, studying local ring at a point.

I would like to hear users view about this book.
I understand that this question has no single answer and it is more like a personal opinion question but I could not stop my self asking about this.

Even hartshorne's book has following review

> The student who wants to get through the technical material of algebraic geo- metry quickly and at full strength should perhaps turn to Hartshorne’s book, however, my experience is that some graduate students (by no means all) can work hard for a year or two on Chapters 2–3 of Hartshorne, and still know more-or-less nothing at the end of it.

What am I supposed to do now.

Comment: If there is a faculty member at your institution that can advise you, I recommend that you bring this question to that advisor.

Comment: You might consider Ravi Vakil's notes, also:
http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/

I think both of your choices (Hartshorne, and Eisenbud/Harris) are good places to start. People's comments amount to the fact neither book is perfect for everyone, which should not be surprising. Maybe try moving back and forth between all three until a favourite emerges.

Comment: @JasonStarr I would ask advisor as well. I just want to know general opinion on studying from others as well.

Comment: @DavidSteinberg I think that is a nice option as well.

Comment: @JasonStarr Can I ask you what would you say if your student asks this question to you. Apologies if this sounds silly.

Comment: I would talk to the student, I would find out the student's background, and then I would give an answer.  For most students, I recommend first reading *some* commutative algebra, e.g., Atiyah-MacDonald, and then I recommend that the student attempt Harthsorne's book.  However, I have helped students read through other books as well.

Comment: You might also want to check Gortz and Wedhorn for schemes. The thing with algebraic geometry is that rarely if ever do books literally overlap. You could read two books on basic algebraic geometry cover to cover and still not know all the contents of the third and that's okay. It's a huge subject. Whatever book you choose I would advise you to strive for the simplest most intuitive possible explanation (in your opinion) for any thing you read so that it sinks in. I would also recommend "commutative algebra with a view towards algebraic geometry" for the algebra.

Comment: @SaalHardali thanks for the suggestion... I will definitely see that book

Comment: Also, regarding the algebra book i mentioned i wouldn't treat it as a texbook but rather as tome. Its huge and full of geometric insights so its perfect for that. A.M. is much more suited for an introduction to the subject.

Comment: @SaalHardali I took course with AM as reference text and I am comfortable with algebra in that

Comment: I learned scheme theory reading Hartshorne after learning varieties ( Shafarevich ), comm alg ( AM+Eisenbud ), but before complex geometry or much advanced diff geom. In particular, I'd say it was my first modern geometry course.  I had the benefit of learning from @JasonStarr though and living with a symplectic geometer.  I think, for my background, geometric inspiration was the only thing missing from Hartshorne.  Having ( later ) read Geometry of Schemes, I think that would have helped, too.  All this by way of concrete example to Jason's earlier comments.

Comment: Reason for down votes?

Comment: @Callus Ok. Thank you for the comment.